# Validation of Apache Commons Configuration Values

Tags: java, validation, apache-commons-config

I'm using Apache's `commons-configuration` (v 1.10) library to provide configuration values for my program. I use a `CompositeConfiguration` of a `SystemConfiguration` and a `PropertiesConfiguration` in order to allow the users to override the properties file with java's `-D` command-line argument.

The problem I'm running into is validation of the values in the configuration (ensure the value of `x` is positive, for example). As near as I can tell, the `commons-configuration` library (neither 1.10 nor 2.0-beta) does not provide any means of validating configuration values. Yes, you can validate an XML document that's used with `XMLConfiguration` (and that's all I hear about if I try to Google an answer to this question). But that doesn't help me with any values that come from the `SystemConfiguration` part of my configuration class.

So, am I missing something? Does the library provide a way to validate values that I'm missing, or is there a java library that's built on commons-configuration that provides validation capabilities? Or will I need to build it into my derivative of `CompositeConfiguration`?